# importing user details into Active Directory from CSV

Tags: powershell

We're moving to a company wide email signature that requires users to have their names, titles and telephone numbers, etc. into Active Directory. I found a [blog post](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/update-active-directory-user-accounts-from-csv-file/) that explain in simple terms how to achieve this.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\psscripts\test user for import.csv' | Set-QADUser -Identity {$_.email}
```

However, when I run the PowerShell script it doesn't import these columns... but no errors are displayed.

- Email
- Fax (which i re-purposed for people's titles e.g. "BSc, CEng, MIET")
- PhoneNumber
- StateOrProvince (re-purposed for peoples ext)
- MobilePhone

All the columns that don't import are ones with either numbers or special characters, I'm not sure if that's something to do with it?

Here's the test item I'm importing (I've tried it with and without quotes around the strings):

```
DisplayName,Title,Company,Fax,Email,PhoneNumber,StateOrProvince,MobilePhone
Alan johnson,Engineering Manager,The Best company,"BEng (Hons)","Test.user@Mycompany.co.uk","+44 (0) 121 222 1547","1071","+44 (0) 793 155 7984"
```

I've ran the get-member command so you can see how powershell interprets the data.  Import-Csv 'C:\psscripts\test user for import.csv' | get-member

```
>    TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
> 
> Name            MemberType   Definition
> ----            ----------   ---------- 
Equals          Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj) 
GetHashCode     Method       int
> GetHashCode() GetType         Method       type GetType() ToString    
> Method       string ToString() Company         NoteProperty
> System.String Company=The Best company DisplayName     NoteProperty
> System.String DisplayName=Alan johnson Email           NoteProperty
> System.String Email=Test.user@myCompany.co.uk Fax            
> NoteProperty System.String Fax=BEng (Hons) MobilePhone    
> NoteProperty System.String MobilePhone=+44 (0) 121 222 1547
> PhoneNumber     NoteProperty System.String PhoneNumber=+44 (0) 793 155
> 7984 StateOrProvince NoteProperty System.String StateOrProvince=1071
> Title           NoteProperty System.String Title=Engineering Manager
```

Comment: Is this an encoding issue with your source file? What does `Import-Csv 'C:\psscripts\test user for import.csv'` look like for you with your sample data

Comment: I think you made a small mistake with your sample data `,"+44 (0) 121 222 1547,1071"` should be `,"+44 (0) 121 222 1547",1071` since now the mobile phone is empty and stateprovince has the mobile number

Comment: Hello, thanks for picking that up.  However, it still doesnt import Fax,
PhoneNumber, StateOrProvince , or MobilePhone.  I've included the get member for your information.  Thanks